# NamedRange reference not working

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to run this code:

```
Sub remove_duplicates()
    Sheets("Report").Select
    On Error GoTo ErrMsg
    ActiveSheet.Range("Report[#Tout]").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=2, Header:=xlYes
    Range("A7").Select
Exit Sub
ErrMsg:
MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

However i always get an erro on the line:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("Report[#Tout]").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=2, Header:=xlYes
```

I have made sure that the sheet is not password protected or anything but I can't seem to find what is wrong with my code.

Comment: Change `Range("Report[#Tout]")` to `Range("Report")` ;)

Comment: R3uK, i just want to kiss you right know !

Comment: Ahaha let's keep it numeric for the moment, I'll post this as an answer first! On fera des bisous plus tard! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `Range("Report[#Tout]")` to `Range("Report")`

You'll see `Range(NamedRange_Name[#...]")` only when you select specific columns in your NamedRange table, but to reference the whole NamedRange, you only need to put its name between brackets!